# Related to entries in categories in a plugin

Tags: categories, relations, elementcriteriamodel

Ok I can do this in twig but after searching high and low I can't find a good example of how to do it in a plugin.

I have a user profile field called interests which holds an array of what they are interested in. I want to pull out all entries that are related to the category id's held in the interests array. So in twig I do this:

```
{% for interest in userinterests %}
    {% for entry in entries.relatedTo(craft.categories(interest)) %}
        <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}           
{% endfor %}
```

In my plugin function I currently have this but it is not returning anything in the array so I'm currently stuck:

```
$userinterests = craft()->users->getUserById($userid)->getContent()->getAttributes();
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->relatedTo = array(
    'sourceElement' => $categories
);
$relatedEntries = craft()->elements->findElements($criteria);
```

I'm not sure what I am supposed to be adding to the relatedTo array but it also could be something else as I'm still trying to get my head around craft.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Lettie. What is `$categories` being set to?

Comment: That's kind of what I need to find out. It's not doing anything at the moment. What I want it to do is hold an array of id's of the userinterests and pull out any entries which have the id as a category in the entires table. Each entry can have multiple categories so may get pulled out more than once but I can deal with that once I get the entries returned that I want to work with. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok worked this one out eventually myself. If anyone else finds this helpful.

```
$userinterests = craft()->users->getUserById($userid)->getContent()->getAttributes();
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->relatedTo = array(
        'targetElement' => $userinterests['relevantFieldToCheckAgainst'],
        'field' => 'EntryFieldToCheckIn'
);
$relatedEntries = craft()->elements->findElements($criteria);
```